# Newton's Method in unconstrained optimization fails to converge

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, examples-counterexamples, newton-raphson

In order to show that Newton's method can produce a sequence of iterates that diverges, an example given in my book is apply Newton's Method to minimize $f(x)={2\over 3}|x|^{3\over 2}$. starting at the initial point $x^{(0)}=1$

And they have given,
  $$x^{(k)} =(-1)^k=
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $k$ is even} \\
-1, & \text{if $k$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

But I don't understand how they have got this.

According to Newton's method,$-f(x^{(k)})=f'(x^{(k)})(x-x^{(k)})$.
$f'(x)= $ 
\begin{cases}
x^{1/2},  & \text{if $x>0$ } \\
-(-x)^{1/2}, & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}
right?

So when k=0,  I get $x^{(1)}$ as  ${-2\over 3}=1(x-1)$
So $x^{(1)}={1\over 3}$.
What have I done wrong? How do I show, $x^{(k)} =(-1)^k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying the **root-finding** Newton's method $x_{n+1}=x_n-f(x_n)/f'(x_n)$, which in fact converges to $0$ in this example (albeit slowly). Generally, this method works okay  for $C^1$-smooth convex functions, such as yours.

But the problem was to *minimize* $f$. The **minimizing** Newton's method is $x_{n+1}=x_n-f'(x_n)/f''(x_n)$  (i.e., the root-finding applied to the derivative). For the given function, it yields
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{|x_n|^{1/2} \operatorname{sign}x_n}{\frac12 |x_n|^{-1/2} } = x_n-2x_n = -x_n
$$
Hence, the method fails to converge. Generally, it works okay for $C^2$-smooth convex functions, but yours is not $C^2$-smooth.